# Kafka Connector to map topic key as document id in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to map the Kafka topic key as the document id while indexing to elastic search using Kafka sink connector. But I am getting an exception that key is null

As mentioned in the below example, I want the key which is "AKA-25" as the document id but the transformations that I am doing are failing. It seems to be working fine if I take any other field from the value like I tried with "empId" that works fine. But my requirement is to map the key.

Can someone please suggest?

**Here is the Connector config:**

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "type.name": "doc",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.ignore": "false",
  "schema.ignore": "true",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
  "topics": "emp_change",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "transforms": "addSuffix,InsertKey,extractKey,dropPrefix",
  "transforms.extractKey.field": "key",
  "transforms.extractKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
  "transforms.InsertKey.fields": "key",
  "transforms.InsertKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey"
  "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "emp_change(.*)",
  "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter", 
  "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "$1", 
  "transforms.addSuffix.replacement": "employee",
  "transforms.addSuffix.regex": ".*",
  "transforms.addSuffix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
  "transforms.createKey.fields": "key"
}
```

**Kafka topic message looks like this:**

```
{
    "topic": "EmpChange",
    "key": "AKA-25",
    "value": {
      "eventType": "EMP_CHG",
      "empId": 1001,
      "empName": "AKASH"
    },
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 0
  }
```

**Here is the exception that I am getting:**

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Key is used as document id and can not be null.
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.convertKey(DataConverter.java:79)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.convertRecord(DataConverter.java:160)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.tryWriteRecord(ElasticsearchWriter.java:285)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.write(ElasticsearchWriter.java:270)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.put(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:169)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got a mistake in your config. As shown in your data you've got a key (`"key": "AKA-25",`) to your message:

```json
{
    "topic": "EmpChange",
    "key": "AKA-25",
    "value": {
      "eventType": "EMP_CHG",
      "empId": 1001,
      "empName": "AKASH"
    },
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 0
  }
```

However, you have a Single Message Transform which instructs Kafka Connect to copy the value of field `key` *in the value of the message* into the key of the message

```
  "transforms.InsertKey.fields": "key",
  "transforms.InsertKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey"
```

But since `key` is not a field in the `value` of the message, the transform is going to insert a NULL in the Kafka message key, and thus the error that you get

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Key is used as document id and can not be null.
```

The correct config to use should be this:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "type.name": "doc",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.ignore": "false",
  "schema.ignore": "true",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
  "topics": "PPAP_C01_ApexUserChange",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "transforms": "addSuffix,dropPrefix",
  "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "PPAP_C01_ApexUserChange(.*)",
  "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter", 
  "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "$1", 
  "transforms.addSuffix.replacement": "users1",
  "transforms.addSuffix.regex": ".*",
  "transforms.addSuffix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter"
}
```

The delta between what you had and this updated config is:

- Remove `ValueToKey` and `ExtractField$Key` transforms
- Remove orphan `createKey` transform config
- Change key converter to `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` and remove corresponding `schemas.enable`